# Entity Framework 6 Persist a MathNet.Numerics Matrix

Tags: c#, entity-framework, matrix, entity-framework-6, mathnet-numerics

We have a class that wraps a [MathNet.Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) matrix:

```
public class Matrix
{
    public MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<double> _matrix { get; set; }

    public int? DatabaseId { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

We need to store this `Matrix` in the database using [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). Entity Framework is presently ignoring this property. I'm using Fluent API mapping and currently have this set up:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Matrix>()
       .HasKey(matrix => matrix.DatabaseId);
```

**How can I use Entity Framework to persist my Math.Net Numerics Matrix wrapper in the database, including the `_matrix` property? What should the table structure be?** (I'm using [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/) so I have to build the tables myself.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know whether this is always a dense matrix internally, or can it also be e.g. sparse or diagonal?

Comment: I would prepare a serialized property of `byte[]` (representing `Matrix<double>`), that means you save that as binary in database. You need another not-mapped property (or even a helper method) to parse/deserialize `byte[]` into `Matrix<double>`. However that deserialized property or helper method cannot be used in the Linq-To-Entity query.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need some kind of surrogate to do this in a sensible way, so it actually writes a string or a binary blob to the database (instead of trying to decompose the type and its members).

For example, you could serialize it into [MatrixMarket](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/MatrixMarket.html) format (string, optionally compressed to a binary stream; very simple but you could loose some precision), or [MATLAB](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/MatlabFiles.html) (binary stream; currently only the old Level-5 format supported).